# How to remove odd styles for inputs on Android Chrome?

Tags: css

I have the following input:

```
<input name="email" type="text">
```

And some css for it:

```
border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance:    none;
appearance:         none;
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:    none;
  appearance:         none;
}
```

```html
<input name="email" type="text" />
```

On chrome on android (4.4.2), it appears quite strange:

[image]

Any suggestions how to remove the ugly styling around the input?

Comment: Define "ugly" and why remove the default styles at all?

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you see the double border (not sure if it's a border) on the left and at the bottom on the input? And because this is a client requirement.

Comment: Could be the `outline` or `box-shadow`

Comment: It's the default appearance of Android Chrome.  Are you sure -webkit-appearance:none is applied to the INPUT element?

Comment: @Paulie_D Tried removing both. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

copy this from http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/a-reset-for-forms/
seem pretty complete to me, give it a try?

```css
//FORM RESET

textarea, select, input[type="date"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="email"], input[type="month"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="text"], input[type="time"], input[type="url"], input[type="week"]{

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

-moz-box-sizing: border-box;

box-sizing: border-box;

-webkit-background-clip: padding;

-moz-background-clip: padding;

background-clip:padding-box;

-webkit-border-radius:0;

-moz-border-radius:0;

-ms-border-radius:0;

-o-border-radius:0;

border-radius:0;

-webkit-appearance:none;

background-color:#fff;

color:#000;

outline:0;

margin:0;

padding:0;

text-align: left;

font-size:1em;

height: 1em;

vertical-align: middle;

}

select, select, select{

background:#fff url(data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDQAEAIAAAAAAAP8A/yH5BAEHAAEALAAAAAANAAQAAAILhA+hG5jMDpxvhgIAOw==);

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-position: 97% center;

padding:0 25px 0 8px;

font-size: .875em

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and this is the only topic I found on this issue, albeit unanswered :( I tested it on Chrome 42 for Android 4.2.2 and after a bit I found that adding

`border-radius:1px`

on the inputs/selects forced the my custom border to be even on all sides with no visual artifacts. This is an empirical solution. Hopefully someone else has a better and more documented solution